# Toggle button in boostrap doesn't want to "untoggle"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I'm creating a simple website with Laravela and Vue.js, and website to be responsive I added bootstrap 4. Everything works fine, navbar collapses when it should, and toggle button shows up and when I click it, it displays everything. But when I click the toggle button to hide navbar it just flickers and doesn't do anything.

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">website<span id = "EditorColorist">editor colorist</span></a>
           <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#collapsibleNavId">
                <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="/">HOME</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="/about">ABOUT</a>
                   </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </nav>
 <!--Navigation bar-->
```

And yes I added JS, Jquery before CSS.

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example please

Comment: It already is in.

Comment: No i mean a working example  where we can see output like in snippet or codepen

Comment: Oh, my bad, give me a minute.

Comment: Ok, I tested it on CodePen, and It works perfectly, is it maybe because I'm using, writing bootstrap 4 code in Vue.js components?

Comment: Well i am not pretty much sure about that may be that the reason

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a simple snippet for this to test and it the toggler on there works just fine for me. Feel free to try for yourself.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">website<span id = "EditorColorist"> editor colorist</span></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId">
       <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You could try checking your css to make sure that you don't have any classes that clash with those that bootstrap uses. I've seen that happen and cause issues with the way the navbar works.